# Access Matlab Table Variables like vector fields of scalar struct?

Tags: matlab

I was under the impression that one could access the Variables in a Table using Variable Names in the same manner as one would access vector Fields in a scalar Struct.  This is not always the case.  In the example below, I build up a small dummy scalar struct `y` with vector fields, then a corresponding table `x` with corresponding column names.

```
   % Build up scalar struct `y` with vector fields

>> y.a=1
   y = a: 1

>> y.a(2)=2
   y = a: [1 2]

>> y.b(1:2)=(1:2)'
   y = a: [1 2]
       b: [1 2]

   % Build up table `x` with corresponding fields (variables)

>> x=table
   x = empty 0-by-0 table

>> x.a=1
   x = a
       _
       1

>> x.a(2)=2
   x =   a
       ______
       1    2

>> x.b(1:2)=(1:2)'
   Warning: The assignment added rows to the table, but did not
   assign values to all of the table's existing variables. Those
   variables have been extended with rows containing default
   values.
   > In table/subsasgnDot (line 285)
     In table/subsasgn (line 67)
   x =   a       b
       ______    _
       1    2    1
       0    0    2

   % Compare outputs

>> x.a(2)
   ans = 0

>> y.a(2)
   ans = 2
```

The problem seems to be that `x.a` *doesn't* necessarily map the rows of variable `a` to the elements of `x.a`.  This can create the pathological variable `a` if one builds up x.a in in chunks, and the first chunk consists of only one element (see `x.a=1` above).

People will pan the building up of tables, but for me, I much more value the reduced, simpler code when speed doesn't matter.

**Is there a simple way or code idiom that can allow me to use Tables *and* use the syntax of scalar arrays with vector fields?**

Without that, I'm left un-rejigging my code to go back to scalar arrays with vector fields, then converting to tables for table operations.  I was trying to be efficient (in terms of coding) by starting off directly with Tables.

One non-ideal work-around is to use `x.a(2,1)=2` instead of `x.a(2)=2`, but again, my aim is to reduce and streamline code rather than make it noisier.

Along the lines of accessing data with the same syntax as for structs of vector fields, **is there a way to suppress the above warning when building up the table not only piece-wise, but one field after another?**

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't `x(2,'a')=2` work?

Comment: To suppress warnings: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thanks for the link to controlling warning messages.  As for `x(2,'a')=2`, I'm trying to find code that is not only streamlined, but which minimally departs from the syntax for accessing scalar structs of vector fields (and preferrably with identical syntax).  That way, I can flip back and forth between tables and structs, depending on whether I'm developing or using the code.  (Tables are friendlier for development).

Comment: I thought that it was possible because it seemed like you can access Variable `a` of table `x` using the same syntax as for a struct `x` with a vector field `a`.  But as my code shows, this isn't the case (though I'm sure that it was TMW's intent).  Having minimal departure from a struct syntax is important to me because this kind of data access is littered throughout dozens of *.mfiles, mostly class methods.